# Unable to access data from service in activity

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin.android

I am building a Xamarin.Android application.  I have a working service, and I am trying to get data from that service to an activity that I have.  I know that people get upset over too much code being posted, but I am unsure where my issue is.  I am going post what I think is necessary:

**Service**

```
[Service]
public class DataService : Service
{

    public List<MyObjects> MyObjectList { get; private set; }
    public IBinder Binder { get; private set; }
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        this.Binder = new DataServiceBinder(this);
        return this.Binder;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity)), 0);
        StartForeground(NotificationID, GetNotification("Started Sync"));
        //Do some work here to instantiate and populate the List
    }
}
```

**Service Binder**

```
public class DataServiceBinder : Binder
{
    public DataServiceBinder(DataService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }

    public DataService Service { get; private set; }
}
```

**Service Connection**

```
public class DataServiceConnection : Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        public DataService Service { get; private set; }
        public DataServiceBinder dataServiceBinder;
        public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            dataServiceBinder = service as DataServiceBinder;
            IsConnected = this.dataServiceBinder != null;

            Service = dataServiceBinder.Service;
            ServiceConnectionChanged?.Invoke(this, true);
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            ServiceConnectionChanged?.Invoke(this, false);
            Service = null;
        }

        public event EventHandler<bool> ServiceConnectionChanged;
    }
```

**Activity**

```
public class MyDataActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private DataServiceConnection DataServiceConnection;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (DataServiceConnection == null)
            {
                this.DataServiceConnection = new DataServiceConnection();
            }

            Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(DataService));
            BindService(serviceToStart, this.DataServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyDataLayout);

            var adapter = new MyDataAdapter(DataServiceConnection.Service.MyObjectList);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DataService));
            BindService(intent, DataServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            UnbindService(DataServiceConnection);
            base.OnPause();
        }
```

In my activity, when I try to pass the adapter the list from the service, the "Service" is null, and there for I get a null reference exception.  Why is my Service null?  Am I not binding my service properly?  For the record, they service is started in the Application context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.  Since connecting to the service is asynchronous I cannot expect the adapter to be able to get data synchronously like this:

```
var adapter = new MyDataAdapter(DataServiceConnection.Service.MyObjectList);
```

Instead, I modified my activity to look like this:

```
public class MyDataActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private DataServiceConnection DataServiceConnection;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (DataServiceConnection == null)
            {
                this.DataServiceConnection = new DataServiceConnection();
            }

            Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(DataService));
            BindService(serviceToStart, this.DataServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            DataServiceConnection.ServiceConnectionChanged += ServiceConnectionChanged;
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyDataLayout);

        }
        private void ServiceConnectionChanged(object sender, bool isConnected)
        {
            if(DataServiceConnection.Service == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if(isConnected)
            {
                var adapter = new MyDataAdapter(DataServiceConnection.Service.MyObjectList);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DataService));
            BindService(intent, DataServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            UnbindService(DataServiceConnection);
            base.OnPause();
        }
```

I also modified my Service Connection as such:

```
public class DataServiceConnection : Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        public DataService Service { get; private set; }
        public MyDataActivity DataActivity;
        public event EventHandler<bool> ServiceConnectionChanged;

        public DataServiceConnection(MyDataActivity myDataActivity)
        {
            DataActivity = myDataActivity;
        }

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            dataServiceBinder = service as DataServiceBinder;
            Service = dataServiceBinder.Service;
            ServiceConnectionChanged?.Invoke(this, true);
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            ServiceConnectionChanged?.Invoke(this, false);
            Service = null;
        }
    }
```

Now my solution only tries to send data to the adapter when the service is connected.  This solution is working for me, and I hope it helps anyone else.